# Understanding GLSL function to draw polygon using distance field

Tags: glsl, polygon

Could someone help me understand the following function that draws a polygon of `N` sides (i.e. 3 being a triangle and 4 being a square):

```
float theta = atan(pos.x, pos.y);
float rotate_angle = 2 * PI / N;
float d = cos(floor(0.5 + theta / rotate_angle) * rotate_angle - theta) * length(pos);
```

What I understand from [this illustration](https://codepen.io/nik-lever/full/ZPKmmx) is that:

1. we're interested in finding the angle indicated by the red curve (call it `alpha`)
2. `cos(alpha) * length` will project the green line onto the blue line
3. by comparing the size of said projection with that of the blue line (radius of circle), we know whether a test point is inside or outside of the polygon we're trying to draw

**Question**

Why does `alpha` equal `floor(0.5 + theta / rotate_angle) * rotate_angle - theta`? Where does `0.5` come from? What's the significance of `theta / rotate_angle`?

**What I have read:**

[1] https://codepen.io/nik-lever/full/ZPKmmx

[2] https://thndl.com/square-shaped-shaders.html

[3] https://thebookofshaders.com/07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, `floor(0.5 + x) = round(x)`. However, because `round(x)` may not be available in some environments (e.g. in GLES2), `floor(0.5 + x)` is to be used instead.

Then, since `n = round(theta / rotate_angle)` gives `edge section index` which contains `pos` (e.g. n =-1, 0 or 1 for a triangle) , `n * rotate_angle` is the angle of `edge center point`(=blue line) which is nearest to the `theta`.

Therefore, `alpha = n * rotate_angle - theta` is certainly relative angle from `pos` to the nearest `center`, where `-rotate_angle/2 < alpha <= rotate_angle/2`.

Checking `pos`'s projection length to the center point direction, it's possible to tell inside or outside. To detect discrete direction of polygon edges('s orthogonal vectors) seamlessly, `round()` function is used.